# Receiving Json as String and converting to Java object

Tags: java, android, gson

I am quite new to java and wish to ask some newbie question. My task is receive a json object through function incomingIM() using a API. Once i receive it as a string pass that json object to serialized function and covert it to java object using GSONE Java Library.

1. My First question is can i pass Json object as string and can i pass in that way.
2. Is that how it can be done in java

> // Receving Json Object in String str and passed to function
>   serialization()

```
public void incomingIM(IncomingImInterface incomingImInterface) {
        String str=incomingImInterface.getMessage();
        serialization(str);


    }
```

> //Using GSON java library for json to java object parsing 
>       // passing value from Json object to java object

```
 public MainActivity(String name,String age){
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;

    }
```

> // accepting json object as string and using GSON library convert it
>   to java object

```
 public static void serialization(String str){
            String userJson= str;
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            MainActivity userSimple = gson.fromJson(userJson, MainActivity.class);
        }
```

Comment: Just test your code, and you'll see. Reading the documentation is another option: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely pass around JSON as a string, and that is the normal way it is done.  Just parse the string with GSON or Jackson when you need it and vice versa.  You can go directly to/from POJOs or you can just use a map.

Many web frameworks (e.g. Spring) will happily automatically convert JSON from string to java-object (POJO) for you if you set them up properly (they tend to leverage Jackson for this).  They'll also convert back when returning responses.  I'd say this is the preferred approach for web code.  If you're not in web code though doing it manually would be quite normal.